# Content Security Policy to include Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have a web application that has a Content Security policy with script-src 'self'. However, there is a Chrome extension that uses scripting specifically on our site that is currently being blocked by our CSP. Is there a way to whitelist this specific Chrome extension and allow script from it to run?

Comment: No, there's no such method. Why does this extension run scripts in the context of the page where it's affected by your CSP instead of running it in the isolated content script where it's independent?